# Uploading mp3 audio, transcode to ogg, and store both files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

What is the best approach to upload an mp3 audio file, transcode it to ogg, and store both files to a storage service (for example, Amazon S3) using Heroku + Rails 4 + Paperclip?

Comment: You probably need to define a paperclip processor, which will work with some installed software on your server. Check this article: http://matthewhutchinson.net/2010/10/25/editing-file-uploads-with-a-paperclip-processor and maybe you can take a look at http://soundconverter.org/ if you use linux

Comment: if you could use 'ffmpeg' for the transcode, i have a bash script you might want to look at  http://pastebin.com/8SAvbdjU